# Where to store the images and fetch them from there URL

Tags: android

I have written a code, it switches some `ImageView` using `ViewPager`. I can't save the images in the `drawable` folders as they take a lot of space. I want to fetch them from URLs.

The only confusion I have is about image storage. Where should I store all these images so that they could be fetched easily from their URLs ?

Here is my code.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    ImageView imageView;

    Context context;
    private String[] GalImages = new String[] { 
        "URLs","URLs"   
        };

    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      Picasso.with(context).load(GalImages[position]).into(imageView);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save it to Database locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you intend to upload the images to a remote server? Then any image storage service with permalink to the image will do.

Comment: any names? I have many images, just want to store them and add there links into my code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/ or https://picasa.google.com/ or http://photobucket.com